# Using a Pull Request of an open source project in production

Tags: python, git, pull-request

I am currently working on a prototype for a project that I would at some point in the near future like to deploy. This is just a Dashboard web application built using an open source tool called [Dash](https://plot.ly/products/dash/).

There is a specific functionality **X** that could **significantly** benefit my project; unfortunately this feature is not supported by my tool. However, there is an open [PR](https://github.com/plotly/dash-core-components/pull/74) at the moment that implements exactly the feature I need.

I have checked the PR out and I can make it work on my machine, I am however a bit worried about what is gonna happen once I deploy.

My question is, what caveats should I keep in mind when checking out this PR and basing my whole project on it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have tested the PR and you are confident that the code-base is safe. You can go and deploy to prod. There are never any guarantee for any open-source software, even if if it is merge on the main repository.

You can use this command to install the package with pip:

```
pip install git+https://github.com/user/project.git@remote_branch_name#egg=commit_id
```

You can also do the same with the **requirements.txt** file:

```
package-one==1.9.4
git+git://github.com/user/project.git@remote_branch_name#egg=commit_id
package-three==1.0.1
```

Comment: This is a great answer, I was thinking of using a setup file to build from source but `pip` is a lot better. Should I also somehow make sure that the package will never be updated?

Comment: Absolutely ! That's the reason why I added in my answer how to fix the installation to a specific commit. Never install on prod something that can be updated and you do not control and test.